# Obtain all followers_ids of a user from twitter using correct pagination

Tags: python, twitter, pagination, tweepy

I am very new to using the tweepy api and have managed to get the followers_ids for a particular unauthenticated twitter user. I would now like to know how to get all the follower_ids for the twitter user as the first call only gives me 5000 ids and the user has a much larger set of followers. I have gone through the tweepy documentation but am still quite unclear about how to actually perform pagination using tweepy cursor. I would really appreciate a simple explanation to how to perform pagination and some help with my current code to perform the aforementioned task of obtaining all followers_ids of a twitter user.

```
 import tweepy
    user = tweepy.api.get_user('someuser')
    cursors = tweepy.Cursor(user.followers_ids, id='screen_name')
    for cursor in cursors.items():
        print cursor.screen_name
```

one error that I am getting while using this is the following:

tweepy.error.TweepError: This method does not perform pagination

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need need to have an authenticated tweepy.API instance first.  I got the same error when I tried

```
user = api.get_user('username')
c = tweepy.Cursor(user.follower_ids)
```

However, this works for me:

```
import tweepy
## first set up authenticated API instance
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for block in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, 'username').items():
  ## do something with the block of 5000 follower ids
```

Hope that helps!